# How to ignore the cell if it is already highlighted with green color

Tags: excel, vba

I have a requirement to match the title from one workbook sheet 1  to another workbook sheet 1 .If the title matches then need to change particular cell color to green and if it is a partial match then color the cell to yellow and if it is not match with any of the title then color to red.While i am doing this all cells are turn to red ..i just want to add some condition like if the cell is already have the green color then ignore that cell to become red but i have the probability to change the green color to yellow color.Kindly help me out to solve this problem

'code for title

```
If InStr(1, plan_Title, pca_Title) > 0 Then
    If (UCase(plan_Title) = (pca_Title)) Then
        Spotpca.Range("E" & j).Interior.Color = rgbGreen
        Spotplan.Range("f" & i).Interior.Color = rgbGreen
    Else
        Spotpca.Range("E" & j).Interior.Color = rgbYellow
        Spotplan.Range("f" & i).Interior.Color = rgbYellow
    End If
Else
    Spotpca.Range("E" & j).Interior.Color = rgbRed
    Spotplan.Range("f" & i).Interior.Color = rgbRed

End If
```

Comment: You may want to read more about [`exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/exit-statement) and [`continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/continue-statement).

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't complete so I'm just guessing you are looping and what I would do is check if the cell is green, if so go to the next row(?)

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub Painting()

    'code for title
        For i = 1 To x
            For j = 1 To y
                If spotpca.Range("E" & j).Interior.Color = rgbGreen Then GoTo Nexttitle 'check if the cell is green
                If InStr(1, plan_Title, pca_Title) > 0 Then
                    If (UCase(plan_Title) = (pca_Title)) Then
                        spotpca.Range("E" & j).Interior.Color = rgbGreen
                        Spotplan.Range("f" & i).Interior.Color = rgbGreen
                    Else
                        spotpca.Range("E" & j).Interior.Color = rgbYellow
                        Spotplan.Range("f" & i).Interior.Color = rgbYellow
                    End If
                Else
                    spotpca.Range("E" & j).Interior.Color = rgbRed
                    Spotplan.Range("f" & i).Interior.Color = rgbRed
                End If
            Next j
Nexttitle:
        Next i

    End Sub
```